# Where is fetch getting it's endpoint value from?

Tags: fetch, auth0

I have the following code, I am using React:

```
// post-post
const queryDatabase = (obj, endpoint) => {
    console.log(obj);

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(obj)
    };

    console.log(endpoint);
    fetch(endpoint, requestOptions)
        .then(data => {return Promise.resolve(data)}
    );
}

export {queryDatabase};
```

For some reason `console.log(endpoint)` prints the endpoint that I am passing in, e.g. `"/users"`, `"/profile"` etc. However, `fetch` is trying to send to `http://localhost:3000/users` so when I try to manually pass in an endpoint I get an error about trying to post to `http://localhost/http://localhost/users`.

Where is `fetch` getting this default `http://localhost:3000` value?

It's only doing this for `POST` requests.

The only environment variables are the following:

```
REACT_APP_AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000
REACT_API_SERVER_URL=http://api.localhost
PORT=3000
```

I also have some other environment variables for Auth0, is Auth0 doing this? I've removed these variables for testing and still nothing.

Comment: You will need to see what is the value of `endpoint` just before it is passed to `fetch`. If it starts with a single forward slash indeed then the URL is relative to the base of the document. A default document base is the origin made of the scheme followed by the authority, in your case `http://localhost:3000`, probably (although this actually needs to be verified). Neither `fetch` nor any other mechanism would automatically turn `/users` into something like `http://localhost/http://localhost:3000/users`, so this isn't about `fetch`, really. See if you have a `base` element in your document.

Comment: No you're right but I've removed those variables and the problems persists. Yeh ok I mean base element or none fetch is doing exactly that or something similar is happening. If that's the case that it's affected by the base element then that needs to be highlighted in the docs.

Comment: It's specified nearly down to the t at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#main-fetch. I understand your frustration very well, believe me, having been there myself many times and ending up the same place with every new technology, but I've learned one important thing -- don't go by Stack Overflow and random blogs on Internet learning say, `fetch`. Find the authoritative documentation source and try to debug your way from there. Sure, it takes more time, but you can't say it isn't explicit enough. If it's inconsistent / ambigous, _then_ submit a bug to WHATWG/Google/Mozilla/etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the `Request` object and pass that through to fetch:

```
const requestOptions = new Request(serverUrl + endpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(obj),
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
});
```

Why bother... use axios or something else, fetch sucks.

EDIT:

Apparently not a problem with fetch. Whatever the case this is the fix.

Comment: This is a poor answer, but the real tragedy is it may lead someone else astray because they'll think there is merit to it. The truth is -- and the documentation can say as much -- there shouldn't be and isn't any difference between the code you say is the answer and what you had in the question. The ability to use `Request` is a convenience, it does not change URL parsing semantics. I've been using `fetch` since it was implemented in Firefox and Chrome years ago. Your fault is somewhere else.

Comment: The real tragedy is this shouldn't be an issue. If this is the fix then it's the fix.